# Rutas y Controladores en Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, controller

tengo mis rutas de prueba y al parecer no están funcionando correctamente,
tengo mi carpeta de routes y mi carpeta de controladores, ya están incluidas en mi archivo index, el problema es que ninguna de las dos funciona, tampoco responde en postman, no tengo idea que pasa,
gracias por la ayuda.

en mi archivo index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");

const app = express();

//routes
const sendEmail = require("./routes/mail.route");

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors("*"));

app.use("/mail", sendEmail);

app.listen(8000, () => {
console.log("server on port 4000");
});
```

en mi carpeta routes/mail.route.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const route = express.Router();

const { test, home } = require("../controllers/mail.controller");

route.get("/mail", test);
//route.get("/home", home);

module.exports = route;
```

y estos son mis controllers/mail.controller.js:

```
exports.test = (req, res) => {
res.send("from test");
console.log("test");
};

exports.home = (req, res) => {
res.send("from home");
console.log("home");
};
```

Comment: Hola, cual es el error que obtienes? Agrega una forma de reproducir el problema para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: hola el error es: Cannot GET /mail y Cannot GET /home  parece que ninguna ruta esta funcionando, no se como correr codigo de node aqui

Comment: Por favor agregalo a tu pregunta, agrega todo lo necesario para reproducir el problema

Comment: ya agrege el contenido completo de mis archivos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu archivo `routes/mail.route.js:`

```javascript
const express = require("express");
const route = express.Router();

const { test, home } = require("../controllers/mail.controller");

route.get("/mail", test); <-- Aqui cambialo por route.get("/", test)
//route.get("/home", home);

module.exports = route;
```

Te debería quedar asi:

```javascript
const express = require("express");
const route = express.Router();

const { test, home } = require("../controllers/mail.controller");

route.get("/", test); <- "/"
//route.get("/home", home);

module.exports = route;
```

Lo que te debe estar pasando es que en postman utilizas la URL: "localhost:8000/mail", y al tener el router.get("/mail", test) deberias usar "localhost:8000/mail/mail".

Pero con la correción indicada arriba debería funcionarte con "localhost:8000/mail" sin probblemas

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu tiempo, hice el cambio y funcionó